# how to pass multiple separator in split function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing javascript questions. I want to `split` a string which have `-.,`. how to pass all three in `split function` I my first test case is passed if I used like this   `str.split('-')` but other test case failed ?
s

```
entensify("May-the-force-be-with-you") should return "May the force be with you".
    sentensify("The.force.is.strong.with.this.one") should return "The force is strong with this one".
    sentensify("There,has,been,an,awakening") should return "There has been an awakening".
```

any better solution to pass all test cases

```
function sentensify(str) {

  //console.log(str.split(/\s*(?:-;|$)\s*/).join(' '))
return str.split('-').join(' ')

}
```

Comment: regular expression....

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx specifying all the characters on which you want to split the string, like `/[-.,]/`.

Multiple characters inside square brackets `[-.,]` means ***searching for any character among the given characters***.

```js
function sentensify(str) {
  return str.split(/[-.,]/).join(' ');
}
console.log(sentensify("May-the-force-be-with-you"));
console.log(sentensify("The.force.is.strong.with.this.one"));
console.log(sentensify("There,has,been,an,awakening"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this to match all three. But if you're just going to `join` the array, it might make more sense to just `replace()` them with a space.

split()

```js
var str= "Instead-of-using-split,and,join.why.not-just-use-replace?"
var sep = /[-,.]/g;
console.log( str.split(sep).join(' ') );
```

replace()

```js
var str= "Instead-of-using-split,and,join.why.not-just-use-replace?"
var sep = /[-,.]/g;
console.log( str.replace(sep, ' ') );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to match any of `. , -`. The special regex characters should be escaped with backslashes.

```
function sentensify(str) {
   return str.split(/[\.,\-]/).join(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex may be used for multiple pattern match; however, if you're looking break on the token and then join with a space, you may want to consider using the `replace()` method.

For convenience, I've placed an example in a test suite:

```js
function sentensify(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-.,]/g, ' ')
}

mocha.setup('bdd')

describe('sentensify', function () {
  let expectation = 'This is a test'
  
  it('translates string from hyphens to spaces', function () {
    expect(sentensify('This-is-a-test')).to.equal(expectation);
  });

  it('translates string from periods to spaces', function () {
    expect(sentensify('This.is.a.test')).to.equal(expectation);
  });
  
  it('translates string from commas to spaces', function () {
    expect(sentensify('This,is,a,test')).to.equal(expectation);
  });
  
  it('translates hyphens, commas, and strings to spaces', function () {
    expect(sentensify('This-is,a.test')).to.equal(expectation);
  });
});

mocha.run()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/7.1.0/mocha.min.css" integrity="sha256-zX6KvfdhTfwaVsK5hogXY+wWW9Nf3wyloswn7WLZ9dg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/7.1.0/mocha.min.js" integrity="sha256-lDr02Gr5QIpJQ/k0/Bxx80/1G80tLKt/lruAK8bIYX0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/expect.js/0.3.0/index.min.js" integrity="sha256-eIk9dgZF9fcJLuPyL6F9ZnhgmRPnG0OLM9Yyh5qLODU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="mocha"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`/\W/` is a regular expression that matches any character that is not a word, includes spaces and punctuation, but does not include underscores.

```js
function sentensify(str) {
  return str.split(/\W/).join(" ")
}
    
console.log(sentensify("The.force.is.strong.with.this.one"));
```